# Last line of drawPath is on the 0,0 coordinates of the screen

Tags: android

I am trying to connect some points on the screen and fill the space between them with some paint, its work but after the last point the path goes to the 0,0 coordinates of the screen its upper left angle, I want when it finish to connect with the first point and for example to draw a rectangle. Here is my code:

```
public void drawFloor() {
        Bitmap bmpFloorPattern = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.floor_pattern6);
        BitmapShader patternBMPshader = new BitmapShader(bmpFloorPattern,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        Path path = new Path();
        path.reset();

        if (points != null) {
            MapPoint temp = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                float x = points.get(i).getX();
                float y = points.get(i).getY();
                if (temp != null) {
                    float deltaX = Math.abs(x - temp.getX());
                    float deltaY = Math.abs(y - temp.getY());

                    if (Math.max(deltaX, deltaY) == deltaX) {
                        x = temp.getX();
                    } else {

                        y = temp.getY();
                    }
                }

                path.lineTo(x, y);
                temp = points.get(i);


            }


            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            if (points.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                    path.lineTo(points.get(i).getX(), points.get(i).getY());
                }
            }

            paint.setShader(patternBMPshader);
            path.close();
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            paint.setShader(null);
        }

        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
```

Comment: To make the `Path` start at a point other than (0, 0), the first operation should be `moveTo()` instead of `lineTo()`.

Comment: This is the answer yes! Please add it like a answer to approve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after the last point the path goes to the 0,0 coordinates of the screen its upper left

If the current point of a `Path` is not the same as the first point, the `close()` method will add a line segment connecting the two to close it. By default, a `Path` starts at coordinates (0, 0), the upper-left corner of the display, which explains the behavior you're seeing. To change the `Path`'s starting point, make the first operation a `moveTo()`, instead of `lineTo()`.